# Single records to multiple records in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new to pandas in python, I have to implement below logic. I know to implement this as a sql query, but needed to know how to implement this in pandas.

I have output from a query as below:

```
startdatetime,endatetime,value
2019-03-26 23:00:00.000,2019-03-27 01:00:00.000,37.86
2019-03-27 01:00:00.000,2019-03-27 03:00:00.000,37.91
2019-03-27 03:00:00.000,2019-03-27 05:00:00.000,34.54
```

I need to split datetime into 15 minute durations retaining the same value, or example:

```
startdatetime,endatetime,value
2019-03-26 23:00:00.000,2019-03-26 23:15:00.000,37.86
2019-03-26 23:15:00.000,2019-03-26 23:30:00.000,37.86
2019-03-26 23:30:00.000,2019-03-26 23:45:00.000,37.86
2019-03-26 23:45:00.000,2019-03-27 00:00:00.000,37.86
2019-03-27 00:00:00.000,2019-03-27 00:15:00.000,37.86
2019-03-27 00:15:00.000,2019-03-27 00:30:00.000,37.86
2019-03-27 00:30:00.000,2019-03-27 00:45:00.000,37.86
2019-03-27 00:45:00.000,2019-03-27 01:00:00.000,37.86
```

Comment: Did the answers below help? :)

Comment: Yes it did help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this, just offering my perspective.

First let's recreate your data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ('2019-03-26 23:00:00.000','2019-03-27 01:00:00.000','37.86'),
    ('2019-03-27 01:00:00.000','2019-03-27 03:00:00.000','37.91'),
    ('2019-03-27 03:00:00.000','2019-03-27 05:00:00.000','34.54')
], columns=['startdatetime','enddatetime','value'])
df['startdatetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startdatetime'])
df['enddatetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['enddatetime'])
```

Now intuitively, I would follow one of two methods:

- `Apply` syntax: we split each row into a group. Feels very intuitive to me, but is generally not a very fast syntax.
- `Join` syntax: we create the time intervals and join the values to them. More closely to the SQL style of doing it. I added the code for this one below.

**Join**

We create the range, and join with the flexible `merge_asof` [function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html). This is a not strict merge, allowing to join for the range. It works well for your example, you might have to tweak a bit if the real data differs.

```
range = pd.date_range(start=df.startdatetime.min(), end=df.enddatetime.max(), freq='15min')
df_range = pd.DataFrame(range, columns=['startdatetime'])
result = pd.merge_asof(df_range, df, left_on='startdatetime', right_on='startdatetime')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) by difference of datetimes converted to minutes, then add 15minutes timedeltas to `startdatetime` created by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), for `endatetime` only shift values and repalce last `NaN`s per groups by original value:

```
df['startdatetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startdatetime'])
df['endatetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['endatetime'])

v = ((df['endatetime'] - df['startdatetime']).dt.total_seconds() / (60 * 15))
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(v)]
df['startdatetime'] += pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='s') * 15 * 60
df['endatetime'] = df['startdatetime'].shift(-1).fillna(df['endatetime'])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
         startdatetime          endatetime  value
0  2019-03-26 23:00:00 2019-03-26 23:15:00  37.86
1  2019-03-26 23:15:00 2019-03-26 23:30:00  37.86
2  2019-03-26 23:30:00 2019-03-26 23:45:00  37.86
3  2019-03-26 23:45:00 2019-03-27 00:00:00  37.86
4  2019-03-27 00:00:00 2019-03-27 00:15:00  37.86
5  2019-03-27 00:15:00 2019-03-27 00:30:00  37.86
6  2019-03-27 00:30:00 2019-03-27 00:45:00  37.86
7  2019-03-27 00:45:00 2019-03-27 01:00:00  37.86
8  2019-03-27 01:00:00 2019-03-27 01:15:00  37.91
9  2019-03-27 01:15:00 2019-03-27 01:30:00  37.91
10 2019-03-27 01:30:00 2019-03-27 01:45:00  37.91
11 2019-03-27 01:45:00 2019-03-27 02:00:00  37.91
12 2019-03-27 02:00:00 2019-03-27 02:15:00  37.91
13 2019-03-27 02:15:00 2019-03-27 02:30:00  37.91
14 2019-03-27 02:30:00 2019-03-27 02:45:00  37.91
15 2019-03-27 02:45:00 2019-03-27 03:00:00  37.91
16 2019-03-27 03:00:00 2019-03-27 03:15:00  34.54
17 2019-03-27 03:15:00 2019-03-27 03:30:00  34.54
18 2019-03-27 03:30:00 2019-03-27 03:45:00  34.54
19 2019-03-27 03:45:00 2019-03-27 04:00:00  34.54
20 2019-03-27 04:00:00 2019-03-27 04:15:00  34.54
21 2019-03-27 04:15:00 2019-03-27 04:30:00  34.54
22 2019-03-27 04:30:00 2019-03-27 04:45:00  34.54
23 2019-03-27 04:45:00 2019-03-27 05:00:00  34.54
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like timeseries data.  And that means that there are going to be problems in the source data.  Relying on the source data to be  without error is ultimately a problem with real world systems.

Therefore, resampling is a reasonable way to treat this data and prepare for inevitable jitter.

Also, at each stage there is a chance to intervene and act on the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

csvdata = StringIO("""startdatetime,endatetime,value
2019-03-26 23:00:00.000,2019-03-27 01:00:00.000,37.86
2019-03-27 01:00:00.000,2019-03-27 03:00:00.000,37.91
2019-03-27 03:00:00.000,2019-03-27 05:00:00.000,34.54""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",", index_col="startdatetime", parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)

# flexibility to statistically pick resampled values should the index
# not be on a ten minute boundary
df = df.resample('15T').last()
df = df.reset_index()

# now that the DataFrame has a ten minute freq index, use it to make the end interval
enddatetime = df['startdatetime']
enddatetime = enddatetime.append(pd.Series(enddatetime.values[-1] +  pd.Timedelta(minutes=15)))
enddatetime = enddatetime.shift(-1).values[:-1]
df['endatetime'] = enddatetime

# flexibility to fill missing values
df['value'] = df['value'].ffill()

# results
print(df)
```